# Site structure on smooth fibered manifolds

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ct.category-theory, sheaf-theory

Let $\mathsf{FB}_{s}$ be the category whose objects are smooth fibered manifolds, and whose morphisms are smooth strong projectable maps. Recall that given fibered manifolds $(\pi:Y\rightarrow X)$ and $(\pi^{\prime}:Y^{\prime}\rightarrow X^{\prime})$, a smooth map $f:Y\rightarrow Y^{\prime}$ is *projectable* if $\pi^{\prime}\circ f=f_{0}\circ\pi$ for some (necessarily unique) smooth map $f_{0}:X\rightarrow X^{\prime}$, and it is *strong* if the projection $ f_{0}$ is a local diffeomorphism. If in addition $f_{0}$ is the identity map on $X$ (or a restriction of it to an open subset of $X$), then we also say that $f$ is *vertical*.

If $U\subseteq Y$ is open, then the restriction $(\pi|U:U\rightarrow\pi(U))$ is also a fibered manifold. Such fibered manifolds will be called *open subfibrations* of $(\pi:Y\rightarrow X)$.

I have noticed that it occurs frequently that there is a contravariant functor $\mathcal{S}:(\mathsf{FB}_{s})^{\mathrm{op}}\rightarrow\mathsf{Ab}$ (the latter is the usual category of Abelian groups) with the property that for any fixed fibered manifold $\pi:Y\rightarrow X$, the family of Abelian groups $\mathcal{S}(\pi|U)$ as $U\subseteq Y$ ranges over all open subsets of $Y$ is a sheaf (in the ordinary sense) over $Y$.

So I figure that there is a Grothendieck topology $T$ on the category $\mathsf{FB}_{s}$ such that these functors $\mathcal{S}$ are sheaves over the site $(\mathsf{FB}_{s},T)$. I also hope/suspect that if such a topology is defined on $\mathsf{FB}_{s}$ and $\mathcal{F}$ is *any* sheaf on $(\mathsf{FB}_{s},T)$, then it has the property that for any fibered manifold $\pi:Y\rightarrow X$, the covering sieves of $Y$ include all open subfibrations (well technically the inclusion maps $i:U\rightarrow Y$) and if we define $\mathcal{F}_{Y}$ to be the restriction of the sheaf to these maps, then $\mathcal{F}_{Y}$ is a sheaf (in the ordinary sense) on $Y$.

Is there such a Grothendieck topology? Is it unique? Is it known/used? I have read about similar constructions for smooth manifolds, but not for fibered manifolds, and not with the specific properties I have outlined.

The primary background/inspiration behind this question is that when one does computations on jet prolongations of fibered manifolds, some types of differential forms (endemic to jet spaces, e.g. contact forms) can be regarded as defining sheaves over the total space of the original fibration (i.e. $Y$ in $\pi:Y\rightarrow X$, not $J^{r}(\pi)$), but in these sheaves the fibration $\pi$ itself appears as a “variable parameter”, and I'd like to understand this structure. This is also the reason why I restricted morphisms to strong maps, since these objects pull back under jet prolongations induced from strong maps between the fibered manifolds.

Comment: It may be best to give a definition of a vertical / nonvertical map, it is not clear from the context.

Comment: @DmitriPavlov I'll probably rewrite the entire question when I get the time. It's bit of a mess anyways, I wrote it when I was very tired.

Comment: The site of fibered smooth manifolds was first considered (implicitly) by Nijenhuis in 1958.  Natural operations in differential geometry are defined as morphisms of sheaves on this site, see the book by Kolář–Michor–Slovák.  For more references, see also Section 4.1 in https://arxiv.org/abs/2011.01208v4 and also Section 3.3 in https://arxiv.org/abs/2111.01095v3.

Comment: @DmitriPavlov Thanks, I'll look these up (I already know the KMS book but I never recalled sites/Grothendieck topologies in it!). In the meantime I rewrote the question to be more focused.